# Regex to skip first word between the tokens

Tags: regex, hive

regexp guru help needed!

I got a string, which looks like:

`WordA1 wordA2 wordAN StartToken Skipword WordB1 WordB2 WordBN EndToken WordV1 WordCN`

and i want to extract `WordB1 WordB2 WordBN` substring, taking everything between StartToken and EndToken and skipping first word inside. Usualy i solve such problems with some pattern like:

`(?<= StartToken )\S+\s\K.*?(?= EndToken )`

The problem is, the system i'm implementing it (hive) does not support "\K" functionality. It's also not possible to use not fixed width lookbehind (SkipWord is not fixed length, unfortunately), like:

`(?<= StartToken \S+\s).*?(?= EndToken )`

Another solution is

`(?<= StartToken )(\S+\s)(.*)?(?= EndToken )`

and take group 2, but it is very hard and requires lots of effort and code change to get exact group number.

So my question is: does anybody have simple elegant solution, which will work on hive and does not require bringing group number into regexp_extract?

Comment: I don't know Hive and how it implements Regex and I might be missing somethig from your question, but wouldn't a simple `/StartToken\s\S*\s(.*)\sEndToken/` do it? At least i tested it using javascript regex and it worked fine: https://regex101.com/r/LWwriD/1/.

Comment: You can skip making the first group and just make a group for `wordB*` - this might work for you `(?<= StartToken )[\w]+(.*)?(?= EndToken )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
(?=(?:\S+\s+){3}EndToken)(?:\S+\s+){2}\S+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/112)

If the string what you want to extract consists of `variable number of words`, then you can try this regex.

```
(?<= )\b(?:(?!(?<=StartToken )\S+\s+).)+(?= EndToken)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/117)

- `(?<= )\b` : means `word-starting point`(bounday)
- `(?= EndToken)` :  roles `ending anchor` in this regex
- `\b(?:(?!(?<=StartToken )\S+\s+).)+` : Avoid the word(`\S+`) which preceded by "`StartToken` " and try matching everything at each `word-starting point`(boundary) to the `ending anchor`.

Comment: This will not work if you add an extra word between `StartToken` and `EndToken`: https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/113

Comment: Doesn't the string what you want is 3-words string? Does the string have variable number of words? Pls, try again `new regex` what I added in my answer.  https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/115

Comment: Your second pattern gets it done, thank you very much! Can you add a few words to explain it's logic?

Comment: @EmaNymton, Just now, I added an explanation for the `regex`. Pls, refer to it again. Thank you:-)

Answer (score 0):

At [this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) I see that besides `regexp_extract` there is also `regexp_replace`.

You might try that instead and select the parts before and after the tokens using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and replace that with an empty string:

[`(?:^.*StartToken \S+\s| EndToken.*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/wu4PWW/1)

- `(?:` Non capturing group
- `^.*StartToken \S+\s` From the beginning of the string matchany character zero or more times followed by `StartToken`, one or more non whitespace characters and a whitespace character.
- `|` Or
- `EndToken.*$)` Match `EndToken` followed by any character zero or more times until the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you, it's a nice idea to think about wiping all extra, not applicable in my case, but nice thought direction